# -bash: docker: command not found

Tags: docker, ssh, windows-7, cygwin

I have windows 7 system which is configured with Cygwin to accept remote connections through ssh. I have docker installed on windows 7 system as well.But when I  ssh into the windows 7 system and run $ docker info
it says -bash: docker: command not found

Comment: Is Docker installed in Windows or Cygwin?

Comment: yes... I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the cygwin path is missing docker. You'll need to update your path in cygwin for that user.

Also be aware [of this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263250/running-docker-under-windows-cygwin-environment).